# File permissions

Tags: php, security, file-permissions

HI all I have a question regarding file permissions.

I have created a log file lets say "logfile.log" which traps certain errors, now in order for it to be writable i set its permissions to 777. But when i do this, it then is accessible to anyone to read via their browser.

how would i go about solving this issue?

thanks

Comment: put it somewhere not on the webserver path? IE: put it in /var/log/mywebserver/logfile.log which PHP can get to but not the apache webserver? ~~ that is to say, have you TRIED this approach?

Comment: i wasnt even aware i could put any files in my host outside the webserver, thanks for this tip!

Comment: ~ well it depends on how your server is setup ... are you using a hosted provider? you should check with them on what's available. but they likely wouldn't complain to opening a log file on /var/log for you if it's hosted. (tip: adding @drachenstern would cause ME to see your comment faster, like how I put @chicane007 at the lead of this comment, just a welcome-how-are-you-tip ... welcome to StackOverflow...)  Also: have you seen http://serverfault.com ?

Comment: @drachenstern thank you for the welcome! i had one more question i would like to ask you, what in your mind is the proper "default" file permission settings for PHP files that reside on a webserver? should it just be strictly readable by the owner and thats it?

Comment: Depends on what you're after ... I would also encourage you to ask that question on http://serverfault.com as I feel that question is best answered in that community. This community is about using the code to write apps, that one is about managing the servers. But to answer your question, the best default is the one that lets the webserver user (like apache or apacheuser, but not the user root, for instance) read most files, write a few, and execute even less. but that's a per file decision. most other users read only or not at all (they can read it online, right?) ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your log file should never be inside a directory that's served up by your webserver.

Also, mode 777 makes your log file writable to *anyone* on the system, and also makes it executable. A more sane mode is 644, or 600 to be a bit (actually two bits) more paranoid.

Comment: OK i put this file outside the webserver directory, but it seems nothing less than 777 will not write to that file, any ideas why this would happen? If i try 644 or 600 the file just doesn't get written to... thanks !

Comment: That should not happen. Is the log file's directory writable and executable for the user that PHP is running as?

Comment: yes, the directory is set to be writable, readable and executable for the owner, the file its self can only be written to if its set to be writable by "others" whether the owner or group are writable is inconsequential....

Comment: FYI for any one else having this issue....

i emailed my host and this is what they say:

If you have not implemented php-cgiwrap, then php is being run as a module of the Apache web server. As such, it runs as the username 'nobody' and any files owned by you would need to have permissions set accordingly to allow this other user to write to those files. 

If you implement php-cgiwrap, then all of your php will run as your actual username,  instead of 'nobody', and this would allow php to modify files owned by you without having to setup open permissions like 777.

Comment: @chicane007 ~ The reason for that is as I responded in the comment above, before I read this answer. It has to do with permissions of the account accessing those files. Best to get your PHP configured how you need it, so get on serverfault and let those guys help you...